# white space beetwen navigation and header in IE7

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

I have to work thinking in this old browser because my client has a Sharepoint 2010 intranet with compability mode problem, that put IE9 shows like iE7. The metatag edge is not the solution to me and now my solution is setup layout and css for IE7.  I don't know why but in IE7 the class `s4-pr s4-notdlg` with `id="s4-topheader2"` put a white space above navigation that I can't fix with css. Look at image[image] In other browser and IE 11 or 9 (without compability mode) don't have this problem. How can I fix it? I can change css height of this elemente, but this crop menu background image and part of text. Really I don't know what is happen.